# stretch octava mark to end of measure

Tags: lilypond

When a note has an octava mark, the end of the mark is at the end of the note. For long notes the visual effect is not satisfying. I would like to end the octava mark at the end of the measure.

This example shows what I mean:

```
\score {
    \new PianoStaff
    <<  
        \new Staff {
            \relative c'' {
                \clef treble \time 3/4
                a4 b c | d8 c b4 a | g2.
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \relative c {
                \clef bass \time 3/4
                a2.
                \ottava #2
                \set Staff.ottavation = #"15"
                b''2.
                \ottava #0
                c,,2.
            }
        }
    >>
}
```

This is the result
[image: This is the result]

I would rather have this
[image]

In order to accomplish that result, I added an extra voice with hidden notes, rendering the wanted result. The hidden voice forces the end of the octava mark to the end of the third note. My question is: is there a better/simpler way to obtain the same result?

This is the version with the 'hidden voice'

```
\score {
    \new PianoStaff
    <<  
        \new Staff {
            \relative c'' {
                \clef treble \time 3/4
                a4 b c | d8 c b4 a | g2.
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \relative c {
                \clef bass \time 3/4
                a2.
                \ottava #2
                \set Staff.ottavation = #"15"
                <<
                \new Voice { \voiceOne b''2. }
                \new Voice { \voiceTwo  \hideNotes a4 b c  \unHideNotes }
                >>
                \ottava #0
                c,,2.
            }
        }
    >>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no easy / nice way to do this. See [OttavaBracket right endpoint?](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/OttavaBracket-right-endpoint-td206329.html)
The code I got from there was:

```
\once \override Staff.OttavaBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-1 . -9.5)
```

where in the pair affect the start and end points of the bracket.

```
 \score {
    \new PianoStaff
    <<  
        \new Staff {
            \relative c'' {
                \clef treble \time 3/4
                a4 b c | d8 c b4 a | g2.
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \relative c {
                \clef bass \time 3/4
                a2.
                \ottava #2
                \set Staff.ottavation = #"15"
                \once \override Staff.OttavaBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-1 . -9.5)
                b''2.
                \ottava #0
                c,,2.
            }
        }
    >>
}
```

---

Update:
I think modifying your original answer on hiding notes seems the best answer to me.
Putting b as 1/3 of value and hiding and unhiding notes works:
 `b''2.*1/3 \hideNotes b b \unHideNotes`.
Shorter code than:
`\once \override Staff.OttavaBracket.shorten-pair = #'(-1 . -9.5)`, and the automatic behaviour that we all want.

```
\score {
    \new PianoStaff
    <<  
        \new Staff {
            \relative c'' {
                \clef treble \time 3/4
                a4 b c | d8 c b4 a | g2.
            }
        }
        \new Staff {
            \relative c {
                \clef bass \time 3/4
                a2.
                \ottava #2
                \set Staff.ottavation = #"15"
                b''2.*1/3 \hideNotes b b \unHideNotes % works
                % b''2.*1/3 s s % doesn't work
                \ottava #0
                c,,2.
            }
        }
    >>
}
```

Comment: Maybe not easy and nice, but it is always easier and nicer than an extra voice. The shorten-pair contains two numbers to add extra space at the left and right side of the octava bracket. The not so nice thing is that the extra space is relative to the notes the bracket is on, so if the length of the measure changes, the second number has to be adjusted accordingly. But anyway it is an improvement! thanks.

Comment: hi Owain, I did not know this * operator (?). I will have a look at the documentation to see what it does. Thanks for adding this to my tool box.

Comment: It's just `b2. * 1/3` 'this note' 'times by' 'a fraction'. It's super handy, you can put multiple voices on 1 line with it. See docs [Scaling durations](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/writing-rhythms?class=%22unnumberedsubsubsec%22#scaling-durations)

Comment: ah, I see. the drawback of this method lies in the consequences for the midi output. I think I'd rather stick to you first suggestion.  But thanks for bringing this to the attention.